# Wagtail 4.2.2 custom sitemap failing with list has no iterator attribute

Tags: wagtail

We have upgraded from wagtail 2.15.6 to 4.1.5 custom sitemap is failing with the following error

Django 3.2.18

> File "./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wagtail/contrib/sitemaps/sitemap_generator.py", line 44, in _urls
> for item in self.paginator.page(page).object_list.iterator():

self.paginator.page(page).object_list is indeed a list

We have the following in urls.py

```
from wagtail.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap as wagtail_sitemap

available_sitemaps = {
    'cms-pages': views.CMSPagesSitemap,
    'static': views.StaticViewSitemap,
}

path(
        'sitemap.xml',
        wagtail_sitemap,
        {'sitemaps': available_sitemaps},
        name='sitemap',
    ),
```

our views are

The CMSPagesSitemap class:

```
from wagtail.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap as WagtailSitemap

class CMSPagesSitemap(WagtailSitemap):
    """Extend the default Wagtail sitemap generator to skip over pages
    which use our custom authentication-required mixin.
    """

    def items(self) -> list:
        items_qs = super().items()
        # Unfortunately we have to do some filtering in code, not at the DB.
        # It's fine for the return value to be an iterable, not a QuerySet:
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#sitemap-class-reference

        items = [instance for instance in items_qs if AuthenticatedUserRequired not in instance.__class__.mro()]

        return items
```

The StaticViewSitemap class

```
class StaticViewSitemap(WagtailSitemap):
    """A manually curated section of the sitemap, focused
    on Django-rendered views we want search engines to know about"""

    changefreq = 'daily'

    CONTACT_PAGE_PLACEHOLDER = 'CONTACT_PAGE_PLACEHOLDER'

    def items(self):
        # At the moment, these are deliberately only for unauthenticated pages.
        import pdb
        pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        url_names = [
            # TODO: replace pre-resolved URLs, above, with the proper contact view URL names
            # when they have been ported from V1 into V2
            '/contact/',
            '/contact/events/',
            '/contact/defence-and-security-organisation/',
            '/contact/export-advice/',
            '/contact/feedback/',
            '/contact/domestic/',
            '/contact/domestic/enquiries/',
            '/contact/international/',
            '/contact/selling-online-overseas/',
            '/contact/selling-online-overseas/organisation/',
            '/contact/office-finder/',
            # These were removed from the V1 sitemap because the pages were 404ing anyway because
            # FEATURE_EXPORTING_TO_UK_ON_ENABLED was not set on production any more, so the views
            # ExportingToUKDERAFormView, ExportingToUKBEISFormView and ExportingToUKFormView have
            # NOT YET been ported to Great V2
            # '/contact/department-for-business-energy-and-industrial-strategy/',
            # '/contact/department-for-environment-food-and-rural-affairs/',
            # '/contact/exporting-to-the-uk/',
            # '/contact/exporting-to-the-uk/import-controls/',
            # '/contact/exporting-to-the-uk/other/',
            # '/contact/exporting-to-the-uk/trade-with-uk-app/',
            # The following are all auto-generated from the urlconf
            'core:cookie-preferences',
            'core:login',
            'core:signup',
            'core:robots',
            'domestic:get-finance',
            'domestic:uk-export-finance-lead-generation-form',  # See location(), below
            'domestic:project-finance',
            'domestic:how-we-assess-your-project',
            'domestic:what-we-offer-you',
            'domestic:country-cover',
            'domestic:uk-export-contact',
            'domestic:market-access',
            'domestic:report-ma-barrier',  # See location(), below
            'search:search',
            'search:feedback',
        ]
        return url_names

    def changefreq(self, item):
        # The Django-rendered pages don't change very often and we can always request
        # a re-crawl if we have something we edit that we want to get out there ASAP.
        # 'Monthly' seems like a reasonable middle ground, even though it might not be
        # respected by search engines anyway
        return 'monthly'

    def location(self, item):
        if item.startswith('/'):
            return item
        elif item == 'domestic:uk-export-finance-lead-generation-form':
            return reverse(item, kwargs={'step': 'contact'})
        elif item == 'domestic:report-ma-barrier':
            return reverse(item, kwargs={'step': 'about'})
        return reverse(item)
```

so it seems to be 'cms-pages': views.CMSPagesSitemap, causing the issue as if I comment this out it works fine